# Java Program to Insert Element in Array

Tags: java, arrays

```
private static int i;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n,num1,num3;
        int arr[] = new int[50];

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number you want in array:");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter any number:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            for (int num = i + 1; num < n; num++) 
            {
                if (a[i] > a[num]) 
                {
                    num1 = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[num];
                    a[num] = num1;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Ascending Order:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println(a[n-1]);

        System.out.println("Enter Last number:" );
        num1= scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("New Array Position: ");
        for(i=0; i<n+1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");

        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter number you want in array:5
Enter any number: 5 2 3 1
Ascending Order: 1 2 3 5
Enter last number: 4
New Array Position: 0 0 0 0
```

it should be like this 1 2 3 4 5 can guys help me thanks

Comment: This looks like an excellent opportunity to step through this with your debugger and see what's going on "under the hood" and figure out why you are receiving your current output!

Comment: you are just print out arr[] without set any data into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

1.While printing arr[i] in the last for loop, you have never touched array arr after declaration 
i.e. `int arr[] = new int[50];` Therefore, output  `0 0 0 0` is as expected.

2.After reading the last number i.e. `num1= scan.nextInt();`, you have not used it anywhere moving forward. How do you think you array will come to know about the last element which is to be added ? :)

Something of this sort will work:

1.After sorting array a, copy it into array arr:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    arr[i] = a[i];
}
```

2.Once you have all the old elements in array arr, read last element in array arr i.e. `arr[n+1] = scan.nextInt();`

3.Here you can again sort the array arr to take last element to the appropriate place.

4.Print array arr:

```
for(int j=0;j<n+1;j++){
System.out.print(arr[j]+" ");
}
```

NOTE: Make sure your n is less than 50. Otherwise you will run into `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Good day thank you for feed back abj1305 i learn something what u said on your comment im not prof.programmer im just beginner :) thank you again

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code,

**This answer based on the output given**

1) you are going to specify a size of your array:

According to the output it is: 5
   but actually you are going to get 4 numbers from the command line, so the first for loop should be only for the 4 elements (Assume that you are going to add last element again, so all elements count in array = 5)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
{
   a[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

2) Second for loop should be goes until 4 elements

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
  {
    for (int num = i + 1; num < n-1; num++) 
    {
        if (a[i] > a[num]) 
        {
            num1 = a[i];
            a[i] = a[num];
            a[num] = num1;
        }
    }
  }
```

3) Ascending order of the array contains only 4 elements, therefore it also goes until 4 elements

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1 ; i++) 
{
     System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
}
```

4) You are going to get last element from the command line, it should assign to the array

```
a[n-1] = num1= scan.nextInt();
```

5)**You have to again re arrange the array**

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    for (int num = i + 1; num < n; num++) 
    {
        if (a[i] > a[num]) 
        {
            num1 = a[i];
            a[i] = a[num];
            a[num] = num1;
        }
    }
}
```

6) Then you have to print the array :

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

}
```

Full code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static int i;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n,num1,num3;
        int arr[] = new int[50];

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number you want in array:");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter any number:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
        {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
        {
            for (int num = i + 1; num < n-1; num++) 
            {

                if (a[i] > a[num]) 
                {
                    num1 = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[num];
                    a[num] = num1;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Ascending Order:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1 ; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
        }
         System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Enter Last number:" );
        a[n-1] = num1= scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            for (int num = i + 1; num < n; num++) 
            {

                if (a[i] > a[num]) 
                {
                    num1 = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[num];
                    a[num] = num1;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.print("New Array Position: ");
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter number you want in array:5

Enter any number:
5
3
2
1

Ascending Order:1,2,3,5,

Enter Last number:
4

New Array Position: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for feed back sir this forum so good i hope one day you could help me again sorry i'm not professional im beginner only thank you sir Minoles Alles